# Are semaphores "complete"?

Tags: concurrency, theory, semaphore

Can every imaginable synchronization problem be solved with judicious use of semaphores? What about weak semaphores?

Comment: Rather than asking us to read your book, please provide what information we need to answer *here* in your question.

Comment: "Can every imaginable synchronization problem be solved with judicious use of semaphores?" Is the question clear? I mentioned chapter 4.3 to reference weak semaphores, you don't need to check the pdf if you already know what a weak semaphore is. (btw it's not "my" book)

Comment: I removed the reference to the book. Here's a related question: can every computing problem be solved with a Turing machine? The answer is yes, because of Turing-completeness/Church thesis. This the same question, but about completeness of semaphores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Agerwala](http://www.springerlink.com/content/k322157637600808/) argues that appropiately extended semaphores are complete. This doesn't answer all my questions, but is on right track. David Seiler has a point too.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Just for example, it's impossible for a system that uses only semaphores for synchronization to provide wait-free guarantees, or even progress guarantees, in the face of third-party code (e.g. a plugin).  A perverse or poorly-written section of code can deny access to a semaphore-guarded section of code to everyone forever.

Comment: I don't think this answers the right question.  The problem is whether semaphores are sufficient to implement all other synchronisation primitives.  I don't think any implementation could withstand injection of incorrect code at arbitrary points, whether it use locks or semaphores or what have you.